# How to control scaling in a Winforms application when autoscaling is not working as expected?

Tags: winforms, .net-4.0

I have a .NET 2.0 Winforms app that was converted to .NET 3.5 and has been  subsequently converted to .NET 4.0.  I'm am not sure if the behavior I am seeing in the new appilcation existed in previous versions and no one ever noticed it before, or if this is new to .NET 4.0 and Windows 7.

When a user goes to the Display settings and changes their font size from "Smaller - 100% (default)" to either "Medium - 125%" or "Larger - 150%", the controls on the forms all grow in size and become too large for the form to display.  The strange part is that the controls seem locked to the form's size, so even if the user adjusts the form's size the controls grow with the form- as a result portions of the controls are always cut off or missing altogether.   This is the case even though the controls are not docked, are only anchored "Top, Left", are all set to AutoSize = False, and AutoSizeMode = GrowOnly.

I have experimented with changing the Anchoring and Docking, but that didn't help.  I have also tried out the code from MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229594%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

The really strange part, in my mind, is that the behavior is inconsistent between forms.  Some forms do not have trouble scaling, with or without the additional Autoscaling code from MSDN.  And I can't see a common factor in the ones that have the problem. Some of the forms have no issues whatsoever, while others do.

I'm hoping this is some behavior that someone else has seen and can point me in the right direction for a solution.  Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Comment: Nothing new in .NET 4.  Focus on the Font properties of the form and the controls.  Having the controls inherit the form's Font is best.  Select the control, right-click Font and select Reset.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper approach to dealing with Auto-scaling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197701/proper-approach-to-dealing-with-auto-scaling)