# Error in the Scaling of a Particular WInForm

Tags: c#, winforms, layout

All, I have authoured a great number of WinForms, and this error is odd in that I have not come accross it before. This form is one of 30+ in this project and is the only one where the scaling is behaving oddly at differing screen resolutions and font scalings.

I am aware of the `AutoScaleMode` property and most of the time I have it set to `Font` to prevent precisely the error I have here. When I launch this form on my 1920x1080 display it is fine

[image: No Problem]

but launching the form on a 1920x1200 display the group boxes seem to resize

[image: Error]

this forces the buttons from the screen and causes general uglyness. I can also get this to occur on my 1980x1080 display if I change the default OS font from 125% to 100%.

The top group box is anchored (Left, Right, Top), the bottom group box is anchored (Left, Right, Top, Bottom). The form is set to and `AutoScaleMode` of `Font`. The other controls are *not* `AutoSized`.

What is the problem and how can I resolve it?

Thanks for your time.

*Edit: The designer file is as follows.*

```
namespace IPACost
{
    partial class CreateNationalDbForm
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.splitContainer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer();
            this.customTreeViewSql = new IPACost.CustomTreeView();
            this.panelBottom = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.buttonRefresh = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.groupBoxBottom = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
            this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.customRichTextBox1 = new IPACost.CustomRichTextBox();
            this.labelInfo = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.groupBoxTop = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
            this.checkBoxInclSNAP = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.comboBoxUnits = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.textBoxIniSize = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.labelName = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.textBoxDbName = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.buttonNoFilter = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.buttonCancel = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.buttonAppend = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer1)).BeginInit();
            this.splitContainer1.Panel1.SuspendLayout();
            this.splitContainer1.Panel2.SuspendLayout();
            this.splitContainer1.SuspendLayout();
            this.panelBottom.SuspendLayout();
            this.groupBoxBottom.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
            this.groupBoxTop.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // splitContainer1
            // 
            this.splitContainer1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.splitContainer1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.splitContainer1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.splitContainer1.Name = "splitContainer1";
            // 
            // splitContainer1.Panel1
            // 
            this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.customTreeViewSql);
            this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.panelBottom);
            // 
            // splitContainer1.Panel2
            // 
            this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(this.groupBoxBottom);
            this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(this.groupBoxTop);
            this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(this.buttonNoFilter);
            this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(this.buttonCancel);
            this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(this.buttonAppend);
            this.splitContainer1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(705, 357);
            this.splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = 199;
            this.splitContainer1.SplitterWidth = 6;
            this.splitContainer1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // customTreeViewSql
            // 
            this.customTreeViewSql.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.customTreeViewSql.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.customTreeViewSql.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText;
            this.customTreeViewSql.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.customTreeViewSql.HotTrackFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Underline, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.customTreeViewSql.HotTracking = true;
            this.customTreeViewSql.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(109)))), ((int)(((byte)(109)))), ((int)(((byte)(109)))));
            this.customTreeViewSql.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.customTreeViewSql.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.customTreeViewSql.Name = "customTreeViewSql";
            this.customTreeViewSql.ShowNodeToolTips = true;
            this.customTreeViewSql.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(199, 320);
            this.customTreeViewSql.TabIndex = 7;
            this.customTreeViewSql.NodeMouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeMouseClickEventHandler(this.customTreeViewSql_NodeMouseClick);
            // 
            // panelBottom
            // 
            this.panelBottom.Controls.Add(this.buttonRefresh);
            this.panelBottom.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Bottom;
            this.panelBottom.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 320);
            this.panelBottom.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.panelBottom.Name = "panelBottom";
            this.panelBottom.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(199, 37);
            this.panelBottom.TabIndex = 7;
            // 
            // buttonRefresh
            // 
            this.buttonRefresh.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom;
            this.buttonRefresh.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            this.buttonRefresh.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(2, 2);
            this.buttonRefresh.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.buttonRefresh.Name = "buttonRefresh";
            this.buttonRefresh.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(195, 33);
            this.buttonRefresh.TabIndex = 8;
            this.buttonRefresh.Text = "Show Database Structure";
            this.buttonRefresh.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.buttonRefresh.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonRefresh_Click);
            // 
            // groupBoxBottom
            // 
            this.groupBoxBottom.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.groupBoxBottom.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
            this.groupBoxBottom.Controls.Add(this.customRichTextBox1);
            this.groupBoxBottom.Controls.Add(this.labelInfo);
            this.groupBoxBottom.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 120);
            this.groupBoxBottom.Name = "groupBoxBottom";
            this.groupBoxBottom.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(480, 188);
            this.groupBoxBottom.TabIndex = 12;
            this.groupBoxBottom.TabStop = false;
            this.groupBoxBottom.Text = "Additional SQL Filtering [WHERE:]";
            // 
            // pictureBox1
            // 
            this.pictureBox1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)));
            this.pictureBox1.Image = global::IPACost.Properties.Resources.Info;
            this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 122);
            this.pictureBox1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
            this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 38);
            this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 2;
            this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // customRichTextBox1
            // 
            this.customRichTextBox1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.customRichTextBox1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.customRichTextBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Consolas", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.customRichTextBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 20);
            this.customRichTextBox1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.customRichTextBox1.Name = "customRichTextBox1";
            this.customRichTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(472, 86);
            this.customRichTextBox1.TabIndex = 3;
            this.customRichTextBox1.Text = "e.g. [B1A].[ProdType] IN (\'AC\', \'NB\', \'AE\')";
            // 
            // labelInfo
            // 
            this.labelInfo.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.labelInfo.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(47, 108);
            this.labelInfo.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2, 0, 2, 0);
            this.labelInfo.Name = "labelInfo";
            this.labelInfo.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(428, 77);
            this.labelInfo.TabIndex = 1;
            this.labelInfo.Text = "This filters the create database result sets for the National Databases. The filt" +
    "ering SQL should only contain a valid WHERE clause on the core data table [B1A]." +
    " The \'WHERE\' Keyword is not required.\r\n";
            // 
            // groupBoxTop
            // 
            this.groupBoxTop.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.groupBoxTop.Controls.Add(this.checkBoxInclSNAP);
            this.groupBoxTop.Controls.Add(this.label2);
            this.groupBoxTop.Controls.Add(this.comboBoxUnits);
            this.groupBoxTop.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.groupBoxTop.Controls.Add(this.textBoxIniSize);
            this.groupBoxTop.Controls.Add(this.labelName);
            this.groupBoxTop.Controls.Add(this.textBoxDbName);
            this.groupBoxTop.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(2, 10);
            this.groupBoxTop.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.groupBoxTop.Name = "groupBoxTop";
            this.groupBoxTop.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.groupBoxTop.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(479, 105);
            this.groupBoxTop.TabIndex = 11;
            this.groupBoxTop.TabStop = false;
            this.groupBoxTop.Text = "National Database Details:";
            // 
            // checkBoxInclSNAP
            // 
            this.checkBoxInclSNAP.AutoSize = true;
            this.checkBoxInclSNAP.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(155, 76);
            this.checkBoxInclSNAP.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.checkBoxInclSNAP.Name = "checkBoxInclSNAP";
            this.checkBoxInclSNAP.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(148, 21);
            this.checkBoxInclSNAP.TabIndex = 14;
            this.checkBoxInclSNAP.Text = "Include SNAP data";
            this.checkBoxInclSNAP.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this.label2.AutoSize = true;
            this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(290, 51);
            this.label2.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2, 0, 2, 0);
            this.label2.Name = "label2";
            this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(160, 17);
            this.label2.TabIndex = 13;
            this.label2.Text = "Default growth rate 20%";
            // 
            // comboBoxUnits
            // 
            this.comboBoxUnits.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.comboBoxUnits.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
            "B",
            "KB",
            "MB",
            "GB",
            "TB",
            "PB"});
            this.comboBoxUnits.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(232, 48);
            this.comboBoxUnits.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.comboBoxUnits.Name = "comboBoxUnits";
            this.comboBoxUnits.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(53, 24);
            this.comboBoxUnits.TabIndex = 12;
            this.comboBoxUnits.Text = "MB";
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 51);
            this.label1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2, 0, 2, 0);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(139, 17);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 11;
            this.label1.Text = "Estimated initial size:";
            // 
            // textBoxIniSize
            // 
            this.textBoxIniSize.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(155, 48);
            this.textBoxIniSize.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.textBoxIniSize.Name = "textBoxIniSize";
            this.textBoxIniSize.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(74, 22);
            this.textBoxIniSize.TabIndex = 10;
            this.textBoxIniSize.Text = "100";
            this.textBoxIniSize.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.textBoxIniSize_Leave);
            // 
            // labelName
            // 
            this.labelName.AutoSize = true;
            this.labelName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(39, 24);
            this.labelName.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2, 0, 2, 0);
            this.labelName.Name = "labelName";
            this.labelName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(112, 17);
            this.labelName.TabIndex = 9;
            this.labelName.Text = "Database name:";
            // 
            // textBoxDbName
            // 
            this.textBoxDbName.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.textBoxDbName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(155, 21);
            this.textBoxDbName.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.textBoxDbName.Name = "textBoxDbName";
            this.textBoxDbName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(287, 22);
            this.textBoxDbName.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // buttonNoFilter
            // 
            this.buttonNoFilter.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.buttonNoFilter.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(258, 313);
            this.buttonNoFilter.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.buttonNoFilter.Name = "buttonNoFilter";
            this.buttonNoFilter.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(104, 33);
            this.buttonNoFilter.TabIndex = 5;
            this.buttonNoFilter.Text = "Run No Filter";
            this.buttonNoFilter.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.buttonNoFilter.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonNoFilter_Click);
            // 
            // buttonCancel
            // 
            this.buttonCancel.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.buttonCancel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(162, 313);
            this.buttonCancel.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.buttonCancel.Name = "buttonCancel";
            this.buttonCancel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(92, 33);
            this.buttonCancel.TabIndex = 4;
            this.buttonCancel.Text = "Cancel";
            this.buttonCancel.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.buttonCancel.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonCancel_Click);
            // 
            // buttonAppend
            // 
            this.buttonAppend.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.buttonAppend.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(366, 313);
            this.buttonAppend.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.buttonAppend.Name = "buttonAppend";
            this.buttonAppend.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(117, 33);
            this.buttonAppend.TabIndex = 6;
            this.buttonAppend.Text = "Run Use Filter";
            this.buttonAppend.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.buttonAppend.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonAppend_Click);
            // 
            // CreateNationalDbForm
            // 
            this.AcceptButton = this.buttonNoFilter;
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(705, 357);
            this.Controls.Add(this.splitContainer1);
            this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.MinimizeBox = false;
            this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(523, 303);
            this.Name = "CreateNationalDbForm";
            this.ShowIcon = false;
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
            this.Text = "Special Processes Options";
            this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.SpecialSqlForm_FormClosing);
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.SpecialSqlForm_Load);
            this.splitContainer1.Panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.splitContainer1.Panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer1)).EndInit();
            this.splitContainer1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panelBottom.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.groupBoxBottom.ResumeLayout(false);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
            this.groupBoxTop.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.groupBoxTop.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer splitContainer1;
        private CustomTreeView customTreeViewSql;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panelBottom;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button buttonRefresh;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelInfo;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button buttonCancel;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button buttonAppend;
        private CustomRichTextBox customRichTextBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button buttonNoFilter;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelName;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBoxDbName;
        private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox groupBoxTop;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBoxIniSize;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox comboBoxUnits;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox checkBoxInclSNAP;
        private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox groupBoxBottom;
    }
}
```

Comment: Those aren't the same.  One has "groupBox2" and the other has "Additional SQL Filtering [WHERE:]".  Otherwise, make sure the anchoring is set correct for the controls.  With different font scaling for the monitors, WinForms will never quite look 100% right.  The other thing to look for is any container controls underneath the visible controls - they may not have the correct dock or anchor settings.

Comment: Hi @LarsTech, cheers for the response. The text on the name is different because I was half way through removing the old group box and adding a new one in a hope that the old one had become corrupt and that was the root cause. I appreciate that the forms will never look the same and others don't; however, the way the group box is resizing in the second example is just odd and I have check the parent control (which is a split container) and this is set to Dock Fill. I have been trhough this with a comb which has fine teeth. Any other hunches?

Comment: The buttons might be in the right place, but the group boxes are both off the form - to the right and the groupBox2 is stretching below it.  Try using the "View" - "Other Windows" - "Document Outline" to examine the control heirarchy.  Most likely, one of these controls does not have its anchor or dock property set correctly.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have checked this and it looks right... This is non-ideal :'[

Comment: Maybe try posting the designer file.

Comment: Thanks very much. I have posted it and had a look through myself. Nothing stands out as a problem - I am tempted to mindlessly redo the design of the entire form in a hope that this will fix the issue; but it is unlikely... Thanks again for your time.

Comment: I recreated your form and it did not reproduce the same screen results.  My form scaled properly when I changed DPI settings.  Only thing left to do is look at any events that might be changing those property settings.

Comment: Man, thanks alot for your help it is most appreciated.

Comment: @LarsTech, I have just redrawn the form and checked the releven actionas at form start up. There is nothing that suggests that I am going to be able to fix this; it is a very strange one, but thanks again...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11197701/50447

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could not establish the exact cause of this problem. However, I did come up with a solution after about a million itterations of form and control settings. It was to insert another `Panel` docked as `Fill` inside `Panel2` of the `SplitContainer` control. This seemingly now prevents any odd scaling issues presumably being inherited from the underlying `SplitContainer`.

It's not an answer to *why* this was going on, but it is a fix and hope hope it can helps someone else.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your solution worked. The blog here explains the bug: http://blog.davidegrayson.com/2013/04/unusable-ui-caused-by-windows-forms.html